# Cannot delete a certain array value introduced from console

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this file.rb and when I run it from terminal, I want to delete a certain input value. However, the array remains the same. Any help, please?

```
   def delete
    print "Introduce the parameter for the delete action"
    delete_value = gets.chomp
    p @array.select { |e| e!= "#{delete_value}"}

    #@second_array = @array.reject! {|x| x == "#{delete_value}" }   
    #puts @second_array
   end
```

Comment: This method does not work either.  def delete
 print "Introduce the parameter for the delete action"
 delete_value = gets
  

 @array.reject! {|x| x == "#{delete_value}" }                              p @array                                                            end

Comment: What's wrong with `b = a.select { ... }`? And why are you doing `"#{delete_value}"` when just `delete_value` should be sufficient? What does `@array` look like and what does `delete_value` look like?

Comment: number = SmartArray.new  
  number.array = [-3,6,5,3,10,6,2,3,9,-3,-2,-5]  and delete_value is an attr_accessor. And I'm calling the delete function through number.delete.

Comment: So you have an array of Fixnum and you're trying to remove a String from it?

Comment: The annoying part is that if I have 'def delete(delete_value)' as parameter and I call it through something like number.delete(3), all methods work. The array doesn't change only when I'm introducing the delete_value from the terminal, when running the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of numbers:

```
@array = [-3,6,5,3,10,6,2,3,9,-3,-2,-5]
```

But your `delete_value` is a string:

```
delete_value = gets.chomp
```

`a == b` is false for every Fixnum `a` and String `b` (and similarly `a != b` is always true) so you'll need to convert `b` to a number with something like:

```
delete_value = gets.to_i
@array.reject! { |x| x == delete_value }
```

Ruby doesn't automatically convert between strings and numbers the way some languages will, you have to make the types match and perform the type conversions by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the sharp response, these newbie mistakes always cost you some time!

Answer (score 0):

This method return a new array with all matches. Your original array will indeed not change at all.

For further reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

Comment: Yes, but if I put a preset value in the delete action, it will work just fine. Same for the reject! method. Any advice on how to make it work?